# How is ydescribe from Yesod.Test used?

Tags: haskell, integration-testing, yesod, yesod-test

I am trying to write tests where one test signs in and then the following tests use the cookie set from the first sign in test.

From what I can see, this is done with `ydescribe`

> Start describing a Tests suite keeping cookies and a reference to the tested Application and ConnectionPool

I attempted to use this in my app by looking at some examples from github repos but had no luck.

Here's my code:

```
module Handler.PostSpec ( spec ) where

import TestImport hiding (postBody)
import Data.Aeson
import Yesod.Test

spec :: Spec
spec =
    ydescribe "Auth" $ do
        yit "logs in to dummy auth" $ do
            request $ do
                addPostParam "ident" "0"
                setMethod "POST"
                setUrl ("http://localhost:3000/auth/page/dummy" :: Text)
            statusIs 303
```

When compiled this gives the error:

```
test/Handler/PostSpec.hs:9:5: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘transformers-0.5.2.0:Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Lazy.WriterT
                             [YesodSpecTree site0] Identity ()’
                     with ‘hspec-core-2.4.4:Test.Hspec.Core.Spec.Monad.SpecM () ()’
      Expected type: Spec
        Actual type: YesodSpec site0
    • In the expression:
        ydescribe "Auth"
        $ do { yit "logs in to dummy auth"
               $ do { request $ do { ... };
                      statusIs 303 } }

      In an equation for ‘spec’:
          spec
            = ydescribe "Auth"
              $ do { yit "logs in to dummy auth"
                     $ do { request $ ...;
                            .... } }
```

What would be the correct way to use ydescribe?

Comment: I think you have the wrong signature for the `spec` value. Check out the yesod scaffolding (`stack new foo yesod-simple`) for a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I have to use yesodSpec as well and pass ydescribe as the second parameter.

Here is a usage example.

```
spec :: Spec
spec = do
    settings <-
        runIO $ loadYamlSettings
            ["config/test-settings.yml", "config/settings.yml"]
            []
            useEnv
    foundation <- runIO $ makeFoundation settings
    yesodSpec foundation $ do
        ydescribe "Tests" $ do
            yit "Test" $ do
               -- Test something
```